# Menu generico utilizando Python,Django e estrutura de arvore

Tags: python, django

Estou criando um menu genérico onde um pai pode ter 1 filho e assim sucessivamente (estrutura de uma arvore) e me surgiu uma duvida de como renderizar os pais em um menu e quando passar o mouse em cima do pai abrir lateralmente seus filhos

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Atualmente eu só tenho esse codigo que pega os pais e filhos tudo junto, gostaria de deixar tudo separadinho mas não sei qual caminho seguir.

```
def details(request,pk):

item = Item.objects.filter(fkmenu_id=pk)

template_name = 'menu/menu.html'
context = {
'items': item
}
return render(request,template_name,context)
```

models.py
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou utilizando mptt que é uma lib para trabalhar com arvores mas até agora nada, caso alguém tenha algum caminho sem o mptt também serve.

Comment: Ok, mas esse codigo não ajuda muito, coloque o codigo da classe `Item`, são persistidos? de que maneira? como vc resolve a a arvore?

Comment: Em tese o nó é o que tem o parent_id=null então no template eu consigo listar fazendo um for no item e vendo se o item.parent_id is none mas eu queria pegar também o filho desse cara.

Comment: Estou desenvolvendo uma app django que utiliza essa lib, no caso, estou apresentando uma `api` em forma de árvore, vc pode ver o resultado [aqui, no heroku](https://work-at-olist-sdn.herokuapp.com/) e a implementação e descrição [aqui no github](https://github.com/Sidon/work-at-olist)

Comment: Alem de desenvolver os modelos, o q vc ja tentou?

Comment: Eu consegui resolver meu problema fazendo um método pra pegar os filhos e dps fiz 1 for dentro de outro pra renderizar no template

Comment: Resolveu o todo problema ou ainda falta algo?

Comment: Consegui solucionar meu problema por completo.

Comment: Crie uma classe menu recursiva que é chamada a cada menu
https://github.com/jazzband/django-simple-menu